# Query for id lookup based off of user email

Tags: php, mysql

Would someone be able to give me a MySQL  relation query for looking up a column value of a table based off of another value of the same table?

For instance, I have a table with 4 columns (id, name, email, password).  How could I look up the the value of the "id" column of a certain user based off of their email in the "email" column and store the result (id) in a variable?

Here's the session() controller function

```
function userIsLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'login')
    {
        if (!isset($_POST['email']) or $_POST['email'] == '' or
            !isset($_POST['password']) or $_POST['password'] == '')
        {
            $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'Please fill in both fields';
            return FALSE;
        }

        $password = md5($_POST['password'] . 'chainfire db');

        if (databaseContainsAuthor($_POST['email'], $password))
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            $_SESSION['authorid'] = $author;
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            session_start();
            unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
            unset($_SESSION['email']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            unset($_SESSION['authorid']);
            $GLOBALS['loginError'] =
                    'The specified email address or password was incorrect.';
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

I've tried

```
SELECT id FROM article WHERE email='$email'
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it?  I'm also not totally sure how to store the result of the query in the `$author` session variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is perfect (with the proviso that you are sanitising the `$email` variable - see the tale of [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)).

```
SELECT id FROM article WHERE email='$email'
```

And to perform that query and set the variable `$author` to the returned value is simply:

```
$author = 0;
if( ( $idFromEmail = @mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM article WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string( $email )."'" ) )
    && mysql_num_rows( $idFromEmail )==1
    && ( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc( $idFromEmail ) ) ){
    $author = $r['id'];
}
```

Rewritten in long form, if the above is too complex to follow:

```
$author = 0;
if( !( $idFromEmail = @mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM article WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string( $email )."'" ) ){
  // SQL Query Failed
}elseif( mysql_num_rows( $idFromEmail )!=1 ){
  // More than, or less than, one row returned
}else{
  $r = mysql_fetch_assoc( $idFromEmail );
  $author = $r['id'];
}
```

Comment: I suggest you write every piece of code on a separate line to make the code more readable, i.e. `$idFromMail = mysql_query(...);
if(mysql_num_rows(...)==1){
$r=mysql_fetch...;
$author = $r['id'];
}`

Comment: Agreed. Normally I would, I just thought I would try something new here.